# Lazy imageLoader not working in device?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, image-loading

I am using `imageLoader` class to load image in background, after that i am setting image in emulator its working. In device its not showing `lazy downloaded` image.

```
private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) 
{
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad)
    {
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }
    (photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
    photoLoaderThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Lazy image loading working fine with emulator,But its not loading in device..

Comment: Where are you storing the image files? Internal directory or SD card? I have mine working fine.

Comment: can i see your implementation

Comment: //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

Comment: am getting blank screen...aft downloaded..

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the problem lies in the downloading or displaying part?

Comment: am not able to find ...but y its working in emulator...can i see urs

Comment: i fixed my problem..i didnt add permission external storage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version of [ImageLoader](https://gist.github.com/3168495) I accompany every ImageView with progressbar. Animations then applied for transitions. I also removed the SD card caching option. You should see most remnant of my modifications.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c)2012 Poohdish Rattanavijai
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.robgthai.lib.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.robgthai.lib.R;

/**
 * This class help handling the Lazyload of the image from given URL
 * @author Poohdish Rattanavijai
 *
 */
public class ImageLoader {
    private static final String TAG = ImageLoader.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int LOG_LEVEL = (HelperUtil.FORCE_EVERY_LOG? Log.DEBUG: Log.INFO);
    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    private File cacheDir;
    private Context context;

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_refresh; // Default icon to display before the image finish loaded

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);
        this.context = context;
        cacheDir=new File(context.getCacheDir(),"LazyList");

        //Find the dir to save cached images
//        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
//            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
//        else
//        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    /**
     * Method for lazy-loading images
     * @param url URL of the image
     * @param activity Activity context, currently unused
     * @param imageView ImageView to display the image
     * @param progressBar ProgressBar for displaying while the image is being load
     */
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url)) //If image is already in the cache
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView, progressBar);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    /**
     * Method for lazy-loading images with the image sliding in from the left replacing the progress bar
     * @param url URL of the image
     * @param context Activity context, currently unused
     * @param imageView ImageView to display the image
     * @param progressBar ProgressBar for displaying while the image is being load
     */
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Context context, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url)){
            if(LOG_LEVEL <= Log.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Found in cache: " + url + "[" + cache.get(url) + "]");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));

            Animation exitAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImageLoader.this.context, R.anim.list_image_slide_left_exit);
            exitAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            exitAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

            Animation enterAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImageLoader.this.context, R.anim.list_image_slide_left_enter);
            enterAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            enterAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            progressBar.startAnimation(exitAnim);
            imageView.startAnimation(enterAnim);
//            if(bitmap!=null){
//                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                if(null != progress){
//                  progress.startAnimation(exitAnim);
//                  progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                }
//                imageView.startAnimation(enterAnim);
////                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            }else{
//                if(null != progress){
//                  progress.startAnimation(enterAnim);
////                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                }else{
//                    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
//                    imageView.startAnimation(enterAnim);
////                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                }
//            }
        }else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, context, imageView, progressBar);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    /**
     * Queue the image to download
     * @param url
     * @param context
     * @param imageView
     * @param progressBar
     */
    private void queuePhoto(String url, Context context, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p= null;
        if(null != progressBar){
            p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, progressBar);
        }else{
            p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        }
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Queue the image to download
     * @param url
     * @param context
     * @param imageView
     * @param progressBar
     */    
    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p= null;
        if(null != progressBar){
            p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, progressBar);
        }else{
            p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        }
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Load image into the view preferably from Cache, otherwise url.
     * @param url
     * @return
     */
    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        //identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(LOG_LEVEL <= Log.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Looking for Image in cache");
        if(b!=null){
            if(LOG_LEVEL <= Log.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Image found");
            return b;
        }

        //from web
        try {
            if(LOG_LEVEL <= Log.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Image not found, download from: " + url);
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            HelperUtil.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ProgressBar progress;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, ProgressBar p){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
            progress = p;
        }
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Controller of the image loader 
     * @author poohdishr
     *
     */
    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView, photoToLoad.progress);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progress;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, ProgressBar p){bitmap=b;imageView=i;progress=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            Animation exitAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImageLoader.this.context, R.anim.list_image_slide_left_exit);
            exitAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            exitAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

            Animation enterAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImageLoader.this.context, R.anim.list_image_slide_left_enter);
            enterAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            enterAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
            if(bitmap!=null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                if(null != progress){
                    progress.startAnimation(exitAnim);
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                imageView.startAnimation(enterAnim);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                if(null != progress){
                    progress.startAnimation(enterAnim);
//                  progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                    imageView.startAnimation(enterAnim);
//                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: @RobGThai Dude have you impemented progress bar in any of the xml layouts ?
Do you have your source code for lazy adapter mate posted anywhere, whole project ?

Comment: @B.rohitNare Don't do it yourself. Use 3rd party libraries such as Universal Image Loader or Picasso and save yourself tons of time and headache.

Comment: @RobGThai Well if im using universal image loader, no point using all these classes know pal. ImageLoader or cache and all. But image loader is working fine with my app. Just need to implement progress update.
Anyhow thanks for post mate :)